# Is it possible to write a COM Server on aix?

Tags: com, aix

Is there a way to write a COM server on aix. I tried using the j-interop, but it allows me to wrap a COM Server in java , but runs only on windows.
How could i achive this on aix. Is it even possible.

Thanks

Comment: Reading the docs, I'd say no.  This was designed to act as the *client* for a legacy Windows DCOM server.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Of course it's possible. Worst case is that you have to reverse engineer all the protocols being used in Windows.

Is it easy? I have no idea. It depends on how well documented those protocols are. Given Microsoft's history, I would say not.

Not being snarky there, just telling it like (I believe) it is.

It may be that someone has tackled this before in which case that would make it easier. A cursory Google search turns up very little on this front.